# Web content editor - help or opinion

Tags: html, css

i want to apply for this job as description below:

---

This employer is looking for a competent and experienced student to create a website. You will be required to update web site content through a content management system online. Initially the employer needs an online store product upload and monthly newsletter/VIP voucher content design. You will need to have HTML skills, experience with content management Back End editing and design ability. Once the website is up and running you will be required for ongoing maintenance.

Experience needed: HTML and Webdesign.

---

Since i'm a second year in uni majoring in IT. I wasn't sure if i'm up to this job so i kinda need you guys opinion or if any of you guys have experience this kinda job before, might give me some hints.

I've learned some programming languages such as HTML, CSS and alittle bit of JavaScript and the experience needed for this job is HTML and webdesign. I'm not sure about creating Newsletters/VIP vouchers and Content Management BACK END editing.

Please advice me what i should do since i've got only that much experiences.

Can i do this job?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn't hurt to apply

Comment: Sounds more like a data-entry job than anything else. HTML is probably necessary since the data entry system accepts HTML. Otherwise nothing special probably. Either way though, this question hardly belongs on SO. Apply and ask them what exactly the job is about, we can't tell you. :)

Comment: Thanks guys, i will try to apply for this job and see what their expectations are. One more thing there, i've seen many "data-entry" job, which i have no idea what the job is about and what we need to know to apply for this kinda job. It normally says in the Experience needed as Strong Communication skills, Friendly... I used to think like data-entry job was all about Microsoft Excel but was it more than just Microsoft Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the employer doesn't know how much goes into back end editing. This would require much more than just HTML and webdesign, they'd need a special developer (php, ASP, .NET whatever) full time just for back end editing/webstore creation (unless they have a pre-built solution).

You might want to contact them and ask for more information about what kind of things they expect, because a bit of HTML and webdesign sounds like a job for someone to make a blog entry every week to me.

Also, this site is for questions and answers on programming. Where I don't mind sharing my thoughts on your problem (I've been there too, it's how I learned PHP), this would be a better question somewhere else (possibly [superuser](http://superuser.com), but I'm not sure on that).

So my advice is, contact the employer, ask specific details about what "Back end editing" means and go from there :)

Comment: Thanks Kyle, yes i reckon it's more than just HTML hey but i'm gonna just apply anyway to see what else they need for that kinda job. I can't contact them though, i can only either apply for it or don't apply, so yea.

Comment: Good luck :) Let us know what they expected of you!